# Can I REALLY migrate to btrfs storage driver just by copying /var/lib/docker?

Tags: docker

[This article](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/) basically says that I can migrate to btrfs storage driver simply by backing up `/var/lib/docker`, emptying the directory, mounting a btrfs partition there, and copying the data back. Afterwards I only need to specify the btrfs storage driver in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

**However**, when I inspect the contents of `/var/lib/docker`, I see that it has a subdirectory named `overlay2` with lots of SHA-named subdirs and gigabytes of data - pretty obviously those are my current images/containers/layers/whatever. Will docker know to pick those up even if it is in a subdirectory that is apparently specific to the storage driver I am migrating *away* from? Is that article correct, or is it outdated and relies on an organization of the `/var/lib/docker` directory that isn't used by current docker?

EDIT: I went ahead and did it, and docker works, but it is repulling/rebuilding everything from scratch. So this raises a different question: can I safely delete `/var/lib/overlay2` now? I only had 24G for a btrfs partition, and `/var/lib/overlay2` takes up 13G, so it does make a difference.